# Increase display resolution horizontally to cut off part of screen , in multi-monitor setup

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, resolution, display

So I have 2 monitors of 1920x1080 resolution each. I am using them in portrait mode so each resolution is 1080x1920.

I have a video which is 2360x1920 i.e. (1080p+200p+1080p)x1920p.

I want to run the video fullscreen, and cut the 200x1920p part in the middle. Is there anyway I can modify my xorg.conf to do this ?

TL;DR - multimonitor setup, wants to increase horizontal resolution of Monitor 1, the "increased" part of the resolution needs to be cutoff (not displayed in screen/hidden).

Is there anyway I can achieve this ?

Thank you.

EDIT- Here is an image demonstrating the setup - [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/54FXn.jpg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xrandr` for this.

First, run it in a terminal to show your display names. You will see each with a resolution and offset (e.g. on my setup, I have a primary display, VGA1, at 1920x1080+0+0 and LVDS1 at 1600x900+1920+180). The + numbers define the coordinates of the top left of each screen, relative to the top left corner of the primary output (where positive X is right, and positive Y is downwards)

The command for changing the start point of an output is `xrandr --output <name> --pos <X>x<Y>` - so with my example, if I wanted to add a 200px offset in between my monitors (a dead zone, essentially, as you describe), the command would be `xrandr --output LVDS1 --pos 2120x180` - this would add 200 pixels to the current offset of LVDS1 (in your case it would be `--pos 1280x0`, but you will need to find the output name from `xrandr`)

This will only change the setting for your current session; to make this change permanent add it to your `~/.xprofile` if it exists; or if it doesn't, create a text file `~/.xprofile` and add that line to it.

Comment: Thank you, I am pretty sure this is exactly what I wanted.I will try and confirm.Thanks